# Java Swing, pause the normal procedure of a program until something happens

Tags: java, swing

I am making a Java Swing app and I want it to store some data. I am using the ObjectInput/OutputStream class and what I want to do is, before I set visible the main frame, read from the disk the files, and then in the program I modify them etc and when I press the close button I want to save the new objects in the same files (replace them).

I though that the    `setVisible()`   function paused the thread until the dispose() function is called. Well I am writing my code after the `setVisible()` function but it runs as soon as the main frame opens. How can I solve my problem?

Btw I am using netBeans and I use the JFrame form.

Comment: Don't override `setVisible`, consider using a `WindowListener` instead. Separate the management of the data from the view of the data so as to decouple it

Comment: @MadProgrammer So you are saying I should add a `WindowListener` that rues the save stuff when I press the Close button? (X)

Comment: Yes.  You should load the data, presumably into some kind of model and "pass" it to the what ever wants to use it.  You could use a `WindowListener`, in this case, to update the model and save it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Load the data into some kind of model.  The model provides setters (where applicable) and getters to allow other classes to access the data, but the model provides the actual management.
2. In this case, you could use a `WindowListener` to detect the `windowClosing` event, update the model with the new data and request that the model persist it.

See [How to Write Window Listeners](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/windowlistener.html) for more details

Answer (score 0):

You can use thread class to pause by using Thread.sleep(), Alternatively use [Swing Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) for the same behavior.